# 301 redirection in opencart

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I am using OpenCart 1.5.6 and I recently moved my store from a subdomain to the main domain. Now I'm trying to redirect some of the old static category pages to the actual opencart category/product pages.

Here is my .htaccess line:

```
Redirect 301 /old-category.html http://www.mydomain.com/my-new-category
```

This rule works fine for most of my URLs but for some of them it takes me to:

[http://www.mydomain.com/my-new-category?*route*=old-category.html](http://www.mydomain.com/my-new-category?_route_=old-category.html)

Some people suggested to use RewriteRule instead or add a question mark in the end, I did try all that but nothing works !

I also tried putting my rules before and after the following block:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Anyone has any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^old-category\.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/my-new-category [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked like a charm :D may I ask what was wrong exactly ?

Comment: You're welcome. 301 rule should come before other rules and you need to restart your browser (or clear cache) to avoid old 301 cache in browser.

Answer (score 0):

**I hope it's work for you**

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

Redirect 301 /old-category.html http://www.example.com/my-new-category?
```

Answer (score -1):

I have an issue with 301 redirect from most category/product pages from my old site.

For instance I made 301 redirect from old page

```
/shop/dekorativnye-plenki/ category/29-derevo?route= product/category&path=25_29
```

to new page

```
/dekorativnye-plenki/derevo
```

But sever redirects me to non existed page

```
/dekorativnye-plenki/derevo?_ route_=shop%2Fdekorativnye- plenki%2Fcategory%2F29-derevo
```

Comment: You should post this as you own thread. Not as a comment here.